# caliburn micro update progress bar using task

Tags: c#, progress-bar, caliburn.micro

i'm having this problem, been using caliburn micro and i'm trying to update my progress bar. but nothing it's happening.
i've read a couple of threads in here about it and i'm stuck, it just doesn't update

could you see what's wrong with my code?
my xaml is this:

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="PbEstadoConfig" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Width="200" Height="30" Margin="6,0,572,0">
```

and in my view model i have the following code:

```
private double _pbEstadoConfig;
            public double PbEstadoConfig
            {
                get { return _pbEstadoConfig; }
                set
                {
                    _pbEstadoConfig = value;
                    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => PbEstadoConfig);
                }
            }

     public void Seguinte()
            {
                var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>ActualizaPB("seguinte"));


            }
    protected void ActualizaPB(string value){
     PbEstadoConfig += 20.0;

}
```

Comment: If you take caliburn out of the picture and bind manually to PbEstadoConfig does it work? If so then it may be that cm's default conventions don't have a setup for progress bars.  Do you see any binding errors in the output window?

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be your lack of maximum/minimum values on your progressbar.

The following is working markup in a caliburn micro project i'm currently working on, I have not had to write any custom conventions

```
    <ProgressBar Name="Progress" Maximum="1" Minimum="0" Margin="0,22,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Height="20"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"></ProgressBar>
```

And the backing property:

```
    public double Progress
    {
        get { return _progress; }
        set
        {
            _progress = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Progress);
        }
    }
```

Comment: jason Massey it works without any sort of problems. rbev i've added the maximum and minimum properties and it's not working. changed the name of the object and matched the property name and nothing whatsoever, it doesn't update using a task or not.

Comment: i've been fiddling with the code trying to get this to work. but still no avail. i tried changing the property name to ProgressValueChanged to see if would change the value. but no luck. any ideas?

Comment: any ideas. this is really nerve racking

Comment: i can't get this to work. it's been racking my head for the past week or so. anyone? does anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

My experience with WPF MVVM programming such as that provided by Caliburn.Micro is that the UI thread will be locked during a long running routine, so the progress bar will not update during a long running routine since that it's on the same thread.  As such, I followed the advice on [this page from Stephen](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.ca/2010/06/reporting-progress-from-tasks.html), and implemented his ProgressReporter class along with the System.Threading library